# Searching for grub configuration file in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos-7, grub2

Im searching for `grub.conf` file in CentOS 7. I cant find it with `locate`(I called `updatedb` before). Where does it stores?

In older versions of CentOS I could find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CentOS7 is using grub2 and the generated `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` rather than the old `grub.conf` format, which is why you can't find it.  The new grub.cfg file is not intended for direct editing, instead you need to modify the source files that are used to generate it.

The files in question are `/etc/default/grub` and the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/`.  In particular, if you are looking to add your own custom entries, then you will want to append a boot stanza to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.  The stanza will look something like this:

```
menuentry "My custom boot entry" {
        set root=(hd0,1)
        linux /vmlinuz-3.11-custom
        initrd /initrd-plymouth.img
    }
```

You can add the usual options to the `linux` line to pass in custom options to the kernel.  Once you have everything looking the way you want it to, you run:

```
grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Then, if you want to alter the default boot entry, you change the `GRUB_DEFAULT` option in `/etc/default/grub` to point to the new stanza you added, by zero indexed position or by name (I prefer name), something like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="My custom boot entry"
```

Comment: I was trying to revert from a custom kernel to stock and this answer was extremely useful in that process. If you have a machine which came with a custom kernel, such as OVH servers, "yum install kernel" will create the necessary files in /etc/grub.d/ and you will just need to run grub2-mkconfig and change GRUB_DEFAULT to get back to a stock kernel.

Comment: If you use UEFI, it's at `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`

Comment: nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg && grub2-reboot 4 && reboot [My favorite part of editing grub, is manually specifying the reboot to entry 4 temporarily, then having it reboot to a rescue iso, then when I reboot the liveISO it reboots back to default entry, aka the OS]

Comment: also with CentOS 7 i found I had to use (hd0,msdos3) aka /dev/sda3 vs (hd0,2)

Comment: Note @sjas is correct except in this specific case it's centos, not redhat, so the path is ```/boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following command:

```
find / -type f -name "grub.conf"
```

You can find any other file name you want by replace it to `grub.conf`.

Comment: This is teaching how to fish, instead of handing out fish. No need to downvote.

Comment: @sjas: except that the file might be called `grub.cfg` so it taught how to fish but not very well. (N.B I'm not the down voter).

Comment: `find / -type f -name "grub.conf" -o -name "grub.cfg"` for grub2 compatibility.